# Validating a CIDR IP to set for an interface

Tags: bash, perl, validation, ip, cidr

I'm writing a bash script, which sets a fixed IP for an interface. I'd set the chosen IP with `sudo ip addr change dev eth0 192.168.3.14/24`.

For this I'll need to validate the user given CIDR IP and came across this perl command: `perl -MNet::CIDR=cidrvalidate -e 'printf("%s\n", cidrvalidate($ARGV[0]) ? "valid" : "invalid")' -- 1.2.3.0/24`

Now this would be a great one-liner for the bash script, but it only checks if it is a valid network, not if it's valid client IP on the network.

Bash-only solutions become rather extensive quickly, so I'd be fine to use perl or python for this.

I could not identify the appropriate perl command to check if the user entered a valid client IP (CIDR).

I started implementing a regex check in bash, but that became rather extensive quickly.

This perl command almost does the job perfectly, except it states client IPs on the network are "invalid".
`perl -MNet::CIDR=cidrvalidate -e 'printf("%s\n", cidrvalidate($ARGV[0]) ? "valid" : "invalid")' -- 1.2.3.0/24`

I'd expect the function to identify valid CIDR client IPs. For example:

`127.0.0.1/32` = True

What perl/python/bash function can I use to check if a user define IP (CIDR) is a valid client IP?

**edit:** I've resorted to using `ipcalc`:

```
        while true; do
            read -p "Enter IP: " ip
            ipcalc=`ipcalc ${ip}`
            if [[ ${ipcalc} =~ "INVALID" ]]; then
                   echo "Invalid."
             else
                       break
            fi
       done
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`find` in Net::CIDR::Lite](http://p3rl.org/Net::CIDR::Lite#$cidr->find()).

```
perl -mNet::CIDR::Lite -E'
    my $c = Net::CIDR::Lite->new;
    $c->add("209.152.214.112/30");
    $c->add("209.152.214.116/31");
    $c->add("209.152.214.118/31");
    for (qw(209.152.214.111 209.152.214.112)) {
        say $c->find($_) ? "$_ valid" : "$_ invalid";
    }
'
```

output

```
209.152.214.111 invalid
209.152.214.112 valid
```